# Memory leak and crash due to several view load in Pageflowview

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have release all the memory the max i could from the applicaiton but the problem is i am not able to find the exact place where i need to release memory because i have already release memory everywhere where it was necessary and i cannot see anything left to be released. Now the class i am utilizing is pageflowview and in this class i have implemented multiple views with multiple tableview within it. Kindly help me out with this. In short the whole application is crashed once the memory is overload.

link for the pageflowview demo is as below :

[Paged Flow view sample example](https://github.com/kejinlu/PagedFlowView)

Comment: Hey @raviraj use brackpoint on delloc method and show

Comment: @raviraj have you checked by adding exceptional breakpoints, Leaks and allocation tools ? If not then try to use them it will give you exact reason and place where the app crashed

Comment: Yes i have tried to look at that instrumental tool but still i didnt find any memory leak only problem is there in the allocation, and i am releasing all the object i could but still it crashes

Comment: It was due to high resolution image uploading in multiple views which is resolved.